# Ubuntu updating issues

Tags: apt, 20.04

So I've been trying to update to Ubuntu 21.10 but after it prepares to update I get this message:

```
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.,
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
W:GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu impish InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F,
E:The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu impish InRelease' is not signed.,
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.,
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
W:Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
```

I've tried other solutions from similar issues, but nothing seems to work. I'm not an expert with Linux so can you guys give me some ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: you should check your file /etc/apt/sources.list, there are lines 7 and 2 double, and your key for the whineHQ is damaged or lost. I would suggest to comment out (add # before the lines) the line with winHQ and if you are unsure both double lines. Then the update may work.

Comment: If this is the correct file, this is what popped up Types: deb
URIs: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu
Suites: impish
Components: main
Architectures: amd64 i386
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key

Comment: I couldn't format the text well but it only showed 6 lines

Comment: suggest to edit your post and include it formatted as code. With apt its a good strategy to a) always make a backup before changing anything unless you really know what you are doing and b) comment out stuff unti it works and then work your way backwards.